# How to add a search bar to layout.html so that it is processed in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make the search accessible from anywhere in the application and processed by the usual method of action in the controller. I really need your help.

the method of action in the "Home" controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchTerm)
{
    return View((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        ? repository.Products.Where(
            c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).ToList()
        : RedirectToAction(nameof(ManList)));
}
```

Going deeper, I'm trying to pass the string `searchTerm` to layout to use it in  (this is how it works in the Index view), but I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ViewData` dictionary for this.

```cs
ViewData["searchTerm"] = searchTerm;

//Then reference this anywhere in the cshtml

@ViewData["searchTerm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from controller to view, You can use `ViewData["xx"]`,`ViewBag.xx` or `TempData["xx"]`.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/) to learn more about how use them and the different between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net core `ViewComponent` to solve this problem. A view component has its own view and backend logic and can be invoked anywhere from the application e-g controllers or views.

You can have a better idea about how view components work by following the article:
[View components in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0)